# Apache Beam SqsIO Messages Acknowledge

Tags: java, aws-sdk, apache-beam, amazon-sqs

I have a data pipeline processor written in Java using Apache Beam 2.46, with AWS SDK v2.

Part of the pipeline includes reading messages as a stream from AWS SQS queue, and then if processing of the message fails rewriting them to the queue.
Beam uses the SqsUnboundedReader class to manage the stream-reading from SQS.

Apparently, after reading a message from the queue, beam gives it a processing timeout of about 2 minutes (unconfigurable) and then deletes the message from the queue.

My pipeline logic requires that I "manually" send the acknowledgements to SQS (meaning, manually delete the read message from the queue).
Is it possible?